# PHP Contact form to email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I used [this post](http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/php-email-contact-form.html) to make a simple ‘contact us’ form. The form collects a few pieces of information (email, name and a message) from your visitor and emails it to you.

Instead of redirecting to a thank you page, I'd prefer it to just print the thank you (or error) text in the same HTML form page.

How can this be done? Where do I need to change to be able to keep the user in the same page and show the confirmation message ("Thank you")?

**Edit:** Found a much simpler way to do this - with [ajax](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form).

Comment: So you want to stay in the same page and get thank you message after submitting the form. Is that correct understand?

Comment: Improving problem description and solution needed.

Comment: Maytham: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion.

1- Change your file name `contact-form.html` to `contact-form.php` 
2- Added include line and edit your form action in `contact-form.php`:

```
<h1>Contact us</h1>
<?php include './contact-form-handler.php'; ?>

<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="#">
```

3- Edit your contact-form-handler.php, disable header and added your thank you with personal message, you can also added some layout and decoration that is left to your fantasy.

```
//header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
echo "Thank you " . $name . "<br />";
echo "We will contact you soon";
```

4- Last thing I will added condition to check if the form is submitted or not

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if (empty... etc
}
```

5- (Optional) To re-fetch the posted values if failed I have added following to the form inputs (3 of them, each field got one with the respective field/variable name):

```
value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) echo $name; ?>"
```

But in general When all this done, I will personally will go through the form and clean it up a little bit. Like if I am check the content in JavaScript it is not necessary to check if the fields are empty, so checking submission form is enough. I have not talk about form security yet against any kind of misuse, this just to make some thoughts when you come so far.

---

**Complete code**

Here is your final results, with extra things I done:

**contact-form.php**

```
<form method="POST" name="contactform" action="#">
    <p>
        <label for='name'>Your Name:</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) echo $name; ?>">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for='email'>Email Address:</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $email_address; ?>"> <br>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for='message'>Message:</label> <br>
        <textarea name="message" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['message'])) echo $message; ?>"></textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
```

**contact-form-handler.php**

```
<?php
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'yourname@website.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{

    if (empty($_POST['name']) ||
        empty($_POST['email']) ||
        empty($_POST['message'])
    )
    {
        $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
    }
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email_address = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if (!preg_match(
        "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i",
        $email_address)
    )
    {
        $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
    }

    if (empty($errors))
    {
        $to = $myemail;
        $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
        $email_body = "You have received a new message. " .
            " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message";

        $headers = "From: $myemail\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

        mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
        //redirect to the 'thank you' page
//header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
        echo "Thank you " . $name . "<br />";
        echo "We will contact you soon";

        $name = "";
        $email_address = "";
        $message = "";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This works fine except it gives me this: `Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\contactform\contact-form-handler.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\contactform\contact-form-handler.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\contactform\contact-form-handler.php on line 13

Error: all fields are required
Error: Invalid email address`

Comment: Therefore I add you number 4, check point 4

Comment: the if statement should surround your code from if(empty part till the end.

Comment: Where exactly do I add that? Sorry I'm a complete amateur.

Comment: I just don't know where to add this `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if (empty... etc
}`

Comment: Ha, I will post the code for for pages, copy and paste them

Comment: That works. Thank you so much for your effort mate!